# checking is datetime value is actually todays date

Tags: c#, .net

I have datetime value represented in string format like

```
2017-02-14 10:02
```

how can I check after parsing is this time is todays date?

Comment: This is a really trivial question. Please can you post what you have tried and why it hasn't worked...

Comment: I tried after parsing mydate == DateTime.Today but it always returns false.

Comment: See @DmitryBychenko answer. Use `mydate.Date` to compare only the date

Comment: Here's another duplicate, which is 100% the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534705/c-sharp-how-would-i-check-if-a-date-that-is-currently-a-string-is-today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare `Date`s only:

```
 DateTime mydate = DateTime.Parse(...);

 if (DateTime.Today == mydate.Date) {
   // If parsed date (mydate) has Today's Date
   ...
 }
```

Please, notice that `(DateTime.Today == mydate)` takes `mydate`s *time* part into account and that's why will return `false`

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
DateTime dt_someDate;
string s_dateString = "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm";
if(DateTime.TryParse(s_dateString, out dt_someDate))
{
   if(DateTime.Today.Date == dt_someDate.Date)
   {
      //the date is today;
   }
}
```

You could also do the reverse operation - parse current date to the same format and compare the strings, but it's preferable to use the `DateTime` objects, in my opinion.